# Help deciding which calendar design is more informative

Tags: website-design, information-design

I have a logging application, where users check-in when they arrive, and the manager gets a full report at the end of the month.

I am in the midst of designing a monthly view for the manager, and instead of him needing to click each day to see how many people arrived, I am trying to aggregate the data, and show him a colorful calendar.

The examples here are just a prototype, and the final result would include gray for weekends and holidays, and wouldn't show anything on days in the future.

Can someone here help me decide which is the more informative way to do this?

> Option 1

[image]

> Option 2

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the screenshots it seems you want to show the complete monthly report at once. If that is the case, I am not sure what the **Green**, **Yellow** and **Red** is supposed to mean as you've mentioned

> instead of him needing to click each day to see how many people arrived

I like the **Grey** representing holidays and weekends. It makes sense.

On the other days you could just have a *counter* like so,

- The first row is a way of indicating (if needed), the warning of low attendance.
- The rest is the way of showing the attendance without any warning flags

[image: calendar view for monthly summary]

Comment: I like what Shreyas has done here. It clearly indicates to the user that the numbers in the middle are the attendance, signifies the count its going against so that in the future if you do have a system that changes the total number of possible attendees and the actual attendance needs to vary on the day then this representation carries that too. And most important of all its not cluttered with a simple design.